# How do I hide query string and rewrite url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've done a bit of searching, and I can't quite find a solution. Here's what I would like. A user types:

```
Case 1: www.example.com/user/profile.php?alias=bob
Case 2: www.example.com/user/bob
```

Both should show up on the user's browser as:

```
www.example.com/user/bob
```

Internally, it should be going to "profile.php?alias=bob"

Currently, I have the following mod_rewrite rules in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Converting alias to query
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ profile.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which works for case 2. For case 1 however, the url still shows up with the full query. How do I get it to show up properly for case 1 as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if the request is using profile.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /user/profile\.php\?alias=([^&\ ]+) [NC]
#redirect to user/[ALIAS]
RewriteRule . /user/%1 [L,R=301]

#extract alias from /user/alias
RewriteRule ^user/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ profile.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @Skyd Edited to put in profile.php. Let me know URLs you tested with and outcome if not correct.